# Is there a way to use Android Material Components with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm starting to learn about React Native and I'd like to know if I can use Android Material Components provided by Google with React Native.

Comment: [one](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design), [two](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui), [three](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit), [four](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements), [and many more](https://www.google.co.id/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_idID770ID770&ei=Yy0yW7irG8Lc9QOZ2ZD4Dg&q=react+native+material+component&oq=react+native+material+component&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l2.4180.5219.0.5414.9.7.0.0.0.0.510.510.5-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..8.1.510....0.q0G_NHmg3fQ)

Comment: Thank you, but I wrote "Android Material Components provided by Google". I'd like to know if I can use the same native components that I use in a java application with react native.